# koa - Wrong http status message when piping response from remote server

Tags: node.js, koa

I have server A and server B. The client requests a file from server A, and server A gets the file from server B. 
This works fine when the client requests a file that exists, but the client receives the wrong http status message when requesting a file that doesn't exist.

**Problem:**

The client receives "404 OK" in the status line when it should be "404 Not Found".  No matter what status code I send, the status message is always 'OK', but the client does always receive the status code I set (301, 402, etc). 
Also, Server A does receive the correct status message, and for whatever reason, server A seems to propagate the status code, but not the message.

Server A code:

```
import request from 'request'

context.response.body = request( my_url );

//request( my_url, (error, response, body) =>
//{
//   console.log( "message: " + response.statusMessage );  //prints 'Not Found'
//});
```

Server B code:

```
context.response.status = 404; 
context.response.message = 'Not Found';
context.response.body = 'Page not found';
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I found a "solution", but I'm hoping there's a better one.
In server A, I changed the code to:

```
let stream = request( my_url );

stream.on( 'response', function( response )
{
    context.response.message = response.statusMessage;
});

contest.response.body = stream;
```

I can't say I'm happy with this though because it seems silly that the status code gets propogated but not the message.

Comment: Can you try `context.response = request(my_url)`?

Comment: @GPX Seems intuitive but unfortunately does not work at all. I get undefined in the response body and even the status code doesn't propogate (which was working before).

Comment: Mm, maybe the `request` module decorates the response. If you're interested in getting to the root cause, can you try calling server B via raw `http`?